# Meaning of 愛されてる証拠だ

Tags: meaning

How do I read this? I think it means proof that that I am loved but I am unsure. Is she saying something like the fact that he is not going to go anywhere (stay by her side) is proof that she is loved?

> 彼女「どうだ？　ちゃんと帰って来た気持ちは」
> 彼「もう……どこにも行ったりしません……」
> 彼女「くすっ、そうか、よかった、愛されてる証拠だ」

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: "That's proof I'm loved (by you)" is certainly one of the possibilities, but I'm not 100% sure. I'd say it's impossible to explain what's going on only from this short excerpt. Please share more text surrounding this.